# How to prove that this series is positive

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For each $s\in\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\operatorname{Re} s> 0\}$, let 
$$F(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s}.$$
How to prove that, for each $0 < s <1$, $F(s) > 0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

group terms in pairs, 1st and 2nd, then 3rd and 4th, etc. Note $1/1^s>1/2^s$, then $1/3^s>1/4^s$, so $1/1^s-1/2^s>0$, also $1/3^s-1/4^s>0$, so $1/1^s-1/2^s + 1/3^s-1/4^s+ ... > 0$.